# extraction of tabular data from pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tabula

I am trying to extract tabular data from the pdf using Tabula however the output is not coming in tabular format.

I am attaching the screenshot of the data.
[image]

```
tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdffile, pages='all', stream = 'True')
```

df_table = pd.DataFrame(tables)

Please assist me with this how it is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Output :-
[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried. Tabula should get you a CSV, does it not do that for you? Or what is the actual problem?

Comment: Hi, please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Specifically an example file, a minimal code example on what you tried and the result of that would be helpful!

Comment: tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdffile, pages='all', stream = 'True')
df_table = pd.DataFrame(tables)    

this is the code